# git how to avoid duplicate commits when receiving the error the tip of your current branch is behind

Tags: git, github

so I have this branch, let's call x01, I did some work there, and when I was gonna push to origin (`git push --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> <my branch>`), I received the message:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its distant counterpart. Complete the remote changes (e.g. ‘git pull’)
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the ‘Note about fast-forwards’ in ‘force push –help’ for details.
```

so I did run a `git pull` and was able to push to master, after a few minutes I saw a test failing, so I made a quick correction and pushed again, now my commits look like this:

```
"MY ORIGINAL COMMIT"   hashcode
"not my stuff"         hashcode
"not my stuff"         hashcode
"not my stuff"         hashcode
"not my stuff"         hashcode
"FIXING THE TEST"      hashcode
```

I don't want those commits that aren't mine to be present in the commit history for this branch, I was able to return back to my original commit with `git reset --hard HEAD~5` but I don't know how to move from here to be able to push only my stuff

ps: git status

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/....' by 5 commits, and can 
be fast-forwarded.
    (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

If I run git pull, I will be back at the same problem

EDIT: appears that I haven't been clean on my situation, so my workflow was like this

there's the master branch

I run a `git checkout -b my_branch` to create my branch

did some work on my_branch, and pushed.
meanwhile, some other people pushed stuff to master
Now I have a fix that I need to implement on my_branch, did the fix

when I'm trying to push the fix, I'm receiving this error: `Your branch is behind by 5 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.`

I did a git pull --rebase

and finally was able to do a git push

however, now my git history for this branch is like this:

```
"MY ORIGINAL COMMIT"
"commit from other people"
"commit from other people"
"commit from other people"
"commit from other people"
"MY SECOND COMMIT"
```

what I want is this:

```
"MY ORIGINAL COMMIT"
"MY SECOND COMMIT"
```

how do I remove the commits that aren't mine from the history?

Comment: You say "when I was gonna push to master", can you be specific what you were doing? What command were you executing? IMO it's unusual to push a dev branch directly to master.

Comment: literally git push --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> <my branch>

Comment: That's a workflow that I've not seen used yet, but it could work. It sounds like you simply want to configure what `git pull` does in this case (probably rebase instead of merge).

Comment: I tried to run a 'git rebase' but I did the same thing as a 'git pull'

Comment: As is the question is not clear; i.e. it's not clear what branches you are pull/pushing to. The question specifically says `when I was gonna push to master` but also uses `<branch>`, `<mybranch>` amongst other references. Please rewrite the question to unambiguously state the branch names (`let's call x01` - this is fine) of relevance and the exact commands and their output that you are running.

Comment: Note also that "edit" edits are not the best way to integrate new info to a question - update the question to be cohesive and meaningful to _new_ readers, [here's a reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/761202)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new branch for this:

1. Make `git status` clean, e.g. commit your current uncommitted changes to a temp branch    with:

   - `git switch -c temp_branch`
   - `git add --all`
   - `git commit -am "Better safe than sorry"`
2. `git reset --hard hash_for_"MY ORIGINAL COMMIT"` - point to the last place you know you definitely want
3. `git switch -c my_new_better_branch` - create a new branch
4. Apply necessary changes:

   - a new commit, and/or
   - `git cherry-pick hash_for_"MY SECOND COMMIT"`
5. `git push` - a new branch without any of the *"not my stuff"* commits

Please note that this does **NOT** rewrite history (no `push --force`). Rewriting history can easily go wrong so should be avoided.